# How to change interval time in Grafana to monitor Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus

I am using Grafana to monitor Kubernetes cluster.
But I see that Grafana just get the metrics every 30s by default. I changed it to 15s (as the picture) but I can not change this to 1s or 2s.

The peak in the picture is drawn every 15s
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhzmq.png)

Who used to modify this one? can you help me? please!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough information in your database to increase this resolution, you can change it in:

*Edit Graph >> Metrics >> Open your Query >> Min Step | Resolution*

Comment: Sorry, but I can not find the "Edit Graph" and "Min Step | Resolution" in my Grafana. Can you describe more clearly? 
But I think my problem is that I don't have enough information. Because I think grafana just get the prameters from Prometheus every 15s. So I think we need to change it!

Comment: Click on the graph title `CPU Usage`, here you can see the _Edit Graph_